# How to rewind time of SKEmitterNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

I'm trying to make particles (implemented with *SKEmitterNode*) conform to a time rewind feature in a game. How could I achieve this?

From the documentation, it seems that accessing individual particles is not a possible solution and the only property that might be helpful is *particleAction*. However, I still don't have an idea of how a single action could be used to achieve this.

If this is not feasible, I assume implementing a simpler version of animations from scratch for the game would be necessary. Any suggestions on that would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want the particles to suddenly reverse direction and then disappear where they initially appeared? I'm pretty sure there's no direct way within the emitter framework. A couple of ideas though: 1. If you can write the effect as an SKShader with a single texture or for a few textures, then you can have a "reverse" shader that runs the thing backwards (needs some hacks to effectively rewind u_time, but I know how to do that). 2. Maybe you can use the SKView's texture(from:) to get frames from the emitter and then animate with those textures in reverse.

Comment: @bg2b Thanks for your comment! The first approach seems interesting but the (correct me if I am wrong) need for a different shader implementation for each different particle would be a scalability issue. Now, for the second suggestion, it seems very promising and I will report back when I have time to further experiment with it!

Comment: I meant to have just one sprite (or some small number), plus a custom shader that animates it by referencing u_time. We have something like this for the game that we're working on where a ship jumps to hyperspace with a sort of warp-and-shrink effect, then pops out of it with an inverse effect that uses basically the same shader but with u_time effectively running in reverse. You'd have a sprite whose texture has a bunch of "particles" and the shader would basically take the place of the emitter node.

Answer (score 0):

It is ugly, but you may be able to do something like this:

```
let time = 5
let action = SKAction.customAction(withDuration:time){
                 node,elapsedTime in 
                 guard let emitter = node as SKEmitterNode else {return}
                 emitter.resetSimulation()
                 emitter.advanceSimulationTime(time - elapsedTime)

             }
```

Comment: Resetting and advancing the simulation is a brilliant idea! However, I believe this isn't a possible solution since the particles are generated randomly and therefore won't necessarily match at an identical simulation time.

Comment: It shouldnt be random, it is built around keyframes,  the only randomness should occur when you initialize or change one of the settings that involve a number of particles

Comment: That would make sense but I did some experimenting before writing the first comment and those were the encountered results. I set up a simple fire particle and, on user input, reset and advanced the simulation to a constant time value. Please let me know if I made any mistake.

Comment: share you example

Comment: Sure! Here it is: https://gist.github.com/renanmagagnin/c29127feecbd0f3719fb9a879a79de17